# List has an issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

My code is:

```
foods2 = list()
while food2 := input("Which food do you like ? ") != "quit":
    foods2.append(food2)
print(foods2)
```

I want the output to be a list from my inputs.

Why is the output `[True, True, True]` when there are three inputs before typing 'quit'?

Comment: Because you're putting the result of the comparison with "quit" into the list. Try some parentheses.

Comment: You should take care to read the output you get. The result isn't `['True', 'True', 'True']` but `[True, True, True]`. The list contains no strings but boolean values.

Comment: I changed the string `'True'` to the boolean `True` in your question. If that wasn't right, change it back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at [Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), the assignment operator `:=` is the lowest of them all. That means that python evaluated the `!=` first and assigned its boolean result to `food2`. You can use parentheses to change evaluation order:

```
foods2 = list()
while (food2 := input("Which food do you like ? ")) != "quit":
    foods2.append(food2)
print(foods2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `( )` to separate the walrus operator and the test:

```
foods2 = list()
while (food2 := input("Which food do you like ? ")) != "quit":
    # ^-------------------------------------------^--- HERE
    foods2.append(food2)
print(foods2)
```

Answer (score 1):

As @tdelaney [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68794803/355230), it's because of operator precedence and a lack of parentheses to override it. Just FYI, here's another way using what is known as a [generator function](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generators).

```
def ask_user():
    while (ans := input("Which food do you like? ")) != "quit":
        yield ans

foods = [inp for inp in ask_user()]
```